# A devious individual or ...?

Tags: word-request

I guess it makes sense that a person’s actions would be devious, but you couldn’t say a person him/herself is devious. For example:

> Danny is a devious person.

Does the above sentence sound natural to you or there is another adjective which can be used to explain someone who commits devious actions in order to achieve a goal?

Comment: My feeling is that this is something you could research a little before asking, you would then come across some nice examples of English usage.

Comment: You were right @djna. Actually I saw the definition by first search on the google, but I did not pay much attention to the examples; thank you again for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People are devious.

One dictionary give the example: "he's as devious as a politician needs to be"

Comment: Which dictionary? A citation would be nice.

Comment: @J.R. search the word "devious" on google; you immediately see: 
1) showing a skilful use of underhand tactics to achieve goals.
"he's as devious as a politician needs to be"...
2) (of a route or journey) longer and less direct than the most straightforward way...

Comment: @A-friend - If that's the case, then the reference appears to be [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/devious). In any case, it's better to say where a quoted definition or usage comes from, rather than merely saying, _"One dictionary gives this example..."_

Comment: You are right @J.R. Thank you very much. But what I see in the following link is not known to be Oxford or something; please have a look on the following link: "https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1RLNS_enIR682IR682&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=devious"

Comment: A-friend - Google uses Oxford as its source.